# Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for Auth: (?). at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a web shop and I want to display name of a logged in user. Now I'm using `Auth` from `'@angular/fire/auth'` and I inject Auth in a constructor as `constructor(private auth: Auth)` but I get this error in browser:

```
Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for Auth: (?).
at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (core.mjs:8763:15)
at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.mjs:8753:16)
at providerToFactory (core.mjs:8799:52)
at providerToRecord (core.mjs:8783:25)
at R3Injector.processProvider (core.mjs:8686:24)
at core.mjs:8517:59
at forEachSingleProvider (core.mjs:8857:13)
at forEachSingleProvider (core.mjs:8854:13)
at new R3Injector (core.mjs:8517:9)
at createInjectorWithoutInjectorInstances (core.mjs:10030:12)
```

This is my code:

product-list.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
     <h1>Welcome to Typher web store, {{user.email}}</h1>
</ng-container>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    NgbModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: 'dev-gumhee1zxgvdei6o.us.auth0.com',
      clientId: 'Uaxgrtoga5oWWJYeZ3xRjDNisMMhNDL9',
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin
      }
    }),
  ],
  providers: [ProductService, AuthService, Auth],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

product-list.component.ts

```
user$ = this.productService.currentUserProfile$;
```

product.service.ts

```
constructor(private firestore: Firestore, private httpClient: HttpClient, private auth: AuthService)

get currentUserProfile$(): Observable<ProfileUser | null>{
    return this.auth.currentUser$.pipe(
      switchMap((user) => {
        if(!user?.uid){
          return of(null);
        }

        const ref = doc(this.firestore, 'users', user?.uid);
        return docData(ref) as Observable<ProfileUser>;
      })
    )
  }
```

auth.service.ts

```
currentUser$ = authState(this.auth);

  constructor(private auth: Auth ,private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private fireServices: AngularFirestore) { }
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue?